# Call a method if all rows of a specific datagridview column have same value

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, datagridview, foreach

Can someone tell me how I check if all the rows of a specific column of a datagridview have the same value.

I have one table called "Courier" that containt multiple shipments. Every shipment has a shipment_state column.
Also the "Courier" table have a column named courier_state.
If all shipmment_state = processed, I want to set courier_state = processed.

I've tried this.

```
foreach(DatagridViewRow rw in dtgridshipment.Rows)
{
 string state = rw.Cells[dtgridshipment.Columns["shipment_state"].Index].Value.ToString();

if(state.Equals("Processed"))
{
  NShipment.UpdateStatus() //Update the status of courier_status with stored procedure
}
}
```

The problem with this is if I have a single row with the "processed" value the courier_state is updated to processed.
I need to set courier_state = processed if all the rows of the shipment_state = processed.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need not to update if `state.Equals("Processed")` failed in any iteration, which means you can stop iteration if the condition fails. So you can try something like this:

```
bool canUpdate = true;

foreach(DatagridViewRow rw in dtgridshipment.Rows)
{
    string state = rw.Cells[dtgridshipment.Columns["shipment_state"].Index].Value.ToString();

    if(!state.Equals("Processed"))
    {
       // Need not to update the since state is not Processed for this row
       // Stop iteration here
       canUpdate = false;
       break;
    }
}
// value of canUpdate remains true if shipment_state for all rows are Processed
// So we check that condition here and call the update
if(canUpdate)
{
    NShipment.UpdateStatus();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You're great.